# ListBox mouse left click event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this `ListBox` in my `XAML` file:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}" Name="HistoryListBox" BorderThickness="0"
         Grid.Row="1" Margin="-2,0,0,0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
         SelectionChanged="History_ListBox_Selection_Changed">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <!--Defines a context menu-->
        <ContextMenu x:Key="MyElementMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Delete from History" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>

        <!--Sets a context menu for each ListBoxItem in the current ListBox-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MyElementMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

As you can see it's have the option that when the user click on item it's call

```
History_ListBox_Selection_Changed
```

And when the user select Rightclick on `ListBox` item the `ContextMenu` Appear.

Now i have a problem that when a user click on the Right button the `History_ListBox_Selection_Changed` trigger and then the `ContextMenu` Appear.

How i can make the `History_ListBox_Selection_Changed` work only when left click on the mouse?

Comment: Why not use the mouse button event and then detect if the selected value was changed from the original value? Instead of using the SelectionChanged event...

Comment: @Saran when i assign the mousedown it's won't trigger

Comment: Use the PreviewMouseLeft(or right)ButtonDown event. I tested and it works on my end. You may also need to add a key down if you'd like to add the option for up/down arrow keys. - You may also want to think about button up instead of down event, depending on how this list will be used by the clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MyElementMenu}"/>
</Style>
```

to

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MyElementMenu}"/>
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="History_ListBox_Selection_Changed">
    </EventSetter>
</Style>
```

And then remove `SelectionChanged="History_ListBox_Selection_Changed"`.

Answer (score 0):

Change "SelectionChanged" Event to "MouseLeftButtonUp" or "MouseLeftButtonDown".